# Attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'x' when reloading a scene

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I'm getting an error message: `Attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'x'` while trying to reload a scene that I previously loaded.

I found that the error occurs due to the following line:

```
bg1.x = bg1.x - scrollSpeed
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error full you get is probably something like:

```
attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'x' (a nil value)
```

That means you have not initialized `bg1.x` correctly. Do it, or use a default value like so:

```
bg1.x = (bg1.x or 42) - scrollSpeed
```

I chose `42` but you probably want something like `0`...